# How to change data by click on element

Tags: javascript, jquery

First of all I have an for each loop which iterate trough the objects:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    // Upgrades
   $('.form-upgrades input').each(function (index) {
     var    $parent = $(this).parent(),
            $content = $parent.html();
            $content = $content.split('~'),
            amount = $content[3],

 $parent.html(
            $('<div class="form-toggle" id="toggle' + uniqueId + '">' +
                '<div class="form-toggle-image">' +
                    '<img src="/img/toggle/ic-toggle' + uniqueId + '.png">' +
                    '<div class="checker"><i class="checker-bar-top"></i><i class="checker-bar-bottom"></i></div>' +
                '</div>'+
                input + name + ' ' + infoBlock + '<br>'+ currency + amount.replace(".", ",") + ' ' + period +
             '</div>')
        );
```

First I set the amount of the second item to zero like this:

```
if (index === 1) {
        amount = '0';
}
```

Because it was always `1.50` but now I want to change it back to 1.50 when an specific element is clicked.

I want to change the `amount` when I click on an element with the id of `toggle_151` simply I thought I could change it with this:

```
  $('#toggle_151').click(function () {
    if (index === 1) {
         amount = '1,50';
      }
   });
```

here is the html code of the element where the amount has to be changed:

```
<div class="checkbox">
   <label for="opifer_form_post_valueset_namedvalues_upgrades_options_153">
   <div class="form-toggle active" id="toggle_153"></div>

    <input type="checkbox" id="opifer_form_post_valueset_namedvalues_upgrades_options_153"  value="153" data-amount="1.50">
                Wellness 
        <br>

        </div>
     </label>
  </div>
```

But it is not working can somebody help me out on this please :)

Comment: Can you create a jsFiddle? And please provide some HTML code too.

Comment: Why `[1].indexOf(index) > 1`? It can never be true, because it would either be `-1` if `index != 1` or `0` otherwise, but never `1` because `[1]` doesn't have more than one element...

Comment: @lolka_bolka Here is the link to what iam rebuilding https://www.sportiom.nl/fitness/abonnement

Comment: And what was not working? You want to change the `data-amount`?

Comment: I want to change the amount if #toggle_151 && toggle_170 is clicked

Comment: Are you receiving an error or what is the problem? please be specific or you are going to receive downvotes

Comment: @Tuco no error, the amount will stay 0 and is not changing

Comment: Are you wrapping with `$(document).ready(function(...){});` ?

Comment: @Tuco yes i wrap my code with an docuemtn ready function

Comment: include some html please

Comment: It is because it loops only once and than it sets it value and it can not be changed by an click event